# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ always has an even number of idempotents.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

$a$ is an idempotent if $a^2=a$.

Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ always has an even number of idempotents.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Right now it looks as if you just copy&paste your homework assignments in here (by looking at your other questions). If that is the case, you should at least try to do it on your own (else you will learn way less to nothing) and tell us, where you get stuck at solving your homework.

Comment: Are you taking $ \Bbb Z_n $ as aditive group or as multiplicative group? Because as aditive group the claim is false.

Comment: @Jonathaniui Any group only has one idempotent element. This must be about rings. Also, note the [tag:integral-domain] tag, which isn't quite appropriate side integral domains only has the trivial idempotents $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

In any commutative ring, if $a$ is an idempotent, then $a'=1-a$ is an idempotent. These idempotents are *orthogonal*, i.e. $aa'=0$.

On the other hand, if $a'$ were equal to $a$, we would have $a^2=0$. This cannot be, as $a=a'\iff2a=1$, which implies $a$ is a unit.

Comment: Not at all: $a=1-a\iff 2a=1$, as with ordinary numbers.

Comment: You're welcome. I also happen to be absent-minded (more than often!).